# How to call functions in c++ and objective-c to each other

Tags: c++, objective-c, flutter, objective-c++

While developing an application with Flutter framework, I have to use `C++` and `Objective-C`.

Sometimes you need to call a function of `C++` from `Objective-C`, and sometimes you need to call a function of `Objective-C` from `C++`.

I looked through several articles but couldn't find the answer I was looking for.

Add test code. This is a simple code.

**objc.m**

```
@implementation Objc
-(int) objcSum:(int)num1 secondInt(int)num2{
    return num1 + num2;
}
```

**Cpp**

```
int MyCpp::sum(int n1, int n2){
    int result = objcSum(n1, n2);
    return result;
}
```

Cannot call `objcSum()`.

**AppDelegate.m**

```
MyCpp* mycpp = [[MyCpp alloc]init];
int res = mycpp->sum(10, 20);
NSLog("@res : %d", res);
```

The myCpp object is not created, and the header file is `imported` but cannot be referenced at all.

**Edit**
Calling `c++` from `objc` was successful.
Based on your answer, I wrote the code as below.
But calling `objc` from `c++` throws an error.

```
///ObjcSum.h

#ifndef objcSum_h
#define objcSum_h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface TDWObject : NSObject

-(NSInteger)addNum:(NSInteger)lhs second:(NSInteger)rhs;

@end

int TDWObjcSum(int num1, int num2);

#endif /* objcSum_h */
```

```
///ObjcSum.mm
#import "objcSum.h"

@implementation TDWObject

-(NSInteger)addNum:(NSInteger)lhs second:(NSInteger)rhs
{
    return lhs + rhs;
}

@end

int TDWObjcSum(int num1, int num2)
{
    return [[TDWObject new] addNum:num1 second:num2]; //Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') to 'int'
}
```

```
///Mycpp.h
class MySum {
public:
    int ObjcCall(int num1, int num2);
    
};
```

```
///MyCpp.cpp
#include "mycpp.hpp"
#include "objcSum.h"

int MySum::ObjcCall(int num1, int num2)
{
    int res = TDWObjcSum(num1, num2);
    return res;
}
```

```
///AppDelegate.mm

MySum* mySum = new MySum();
int res = mySum->ObjcCall(10, 40);
delete mySum;
```

**error code**

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:535:61: Unknown type name 'NSString'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:539:30: Unknown type name 'NSString'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:539:53: Format argument not an NSString
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:540:31: Unknown type name 'NSString'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:540:63: Format argument not an NSString
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSZone.h:19:63: Unknown type name 'NSString'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSZone.h:20:19: Unknown type name 'NSString'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:523:1: Expected unqualified-id
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSZone.h:9:1: Expected unqualified-id
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObject.h:10:1: Expected unqualified-id
too many errors emitted, stopping now
```

Comment: You need to define a C interface on both sides, or use Objective-C++.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a place where I can see a simple example code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `Objective-C` is a strict superset of `C`, there is another language called `Objective-C++` which is a strict superset of `C++`. You can use `Objective-C++` to write in `C++` and `Objective-C` in the same source files.

Another option is to avoid exposing any `C++` and `Objective-C` specific statements and keep it compatible with subset available to both languages (i.e. predominantly `C` language)

### Objective-C++ approach

##### Calling C++ code from Objective-C++

This is quite simple, if you compile your project with Xcode and Apple Clang, just rename the source file extension from `m` to `mm` (e.g. from `objc.m` to `objc.mm`). It will make the compiler accept C++ code in the given source file. E.g. if you have a `C++` header defined like this:

```cpp
// MyCpp.hpp file

#include <string>

struct MyCpp {
    std::string var;
    int sum(int a, int b);
};
```

You can import it in any `mm` file like any other header and seamlessly write C++ code inline:

```objc++
// objc.mm

#import "MyCpp.hpp"

@implementation Objc

- (int)objcSum:(int)num1 secondInt(int)num2{
    return MyCpp{}.sum(num1, num2);
}
```

##### Calling Objective-C++ code form C++

Here the things are a little complicated. C++ as a programming language doesn't define any interoperability interface with Objective-C, so the best you can do is to switch from a compilation unit of C++ language to a compilation unit of Objective-C++ language where both syntaxes are acceptable (usually it merely means switching from `cpp` extension to `mm` extension). Again, assuming you have an Objective-C interface defined like this:

```objc
// MyObjc.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TDWObject: NSObject

- (NSInteger)addNum:(NSInteger)lhs toNum:(NSInteger)rhs;
@end
```

In some C++ class this can be called without any issues, provided the class exists within Objective-C++ compilation unit:

```objc++
// MyCpp.mm

#import "MyCpp.hpp"
#import "MyObjc.h"

int MyCpp::sum(int a, int b) {
    return [[TDWObject new] addNum:a toNum: b];
}
```

---

### C approach

##### Calling C++ code from Objective-C

Both Objective-C and C++ support certain C syntax, so an alternative approach to have both languages callable from each other is to restrict headers to C-compatible statements only. E.g. you can have a header declared like this for a C++ implementation:

```c
// CppSum.h

#pragma once

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int TDWCppSum(int a, int b);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

*(**Side note**: `extern "C"` guard is required in order to avoid C++ naming mangling when linking this header to C++ source code. Otherwise C code would not be able to locate the symbols in the compiled C++ object file)*

The implementation file, however, is not restricted anyhow, so you can use any C++ code your compiler supports:

```cpp
// CppSum.cpp

#include "CppSum.h"

template<typename T>
class MySum {
public:
    T sum(T lhs, T rhs) {
        return lhs + rhs;
    }
};

int TDWCppSum(int a, int b) {
    return MySum<int>{}.sum(a, b);
}
```

In Objective-C it can be used like this:

```objc
// objc.m

#import "CppSum.h"

@implementation Objc

- (int)objcSum:(int)num1 secondInt(int)num2{
    return TDWCppSum(num1, num2);
}
```

##### Calling Objective-C code from C++

The approach is pretty much the same: use only C statements in a header, and don't expose any Objective-C implementation there (like `@interface` or `@protocol` statements):

```c
// ObjcSum.h

#pragma once

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int TDWObjcSum(int a, int b);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

And again, you can use whatever Objective-C features you want in the implementation:

```objc
// ObjcSum.m

#import "ObjcSum.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TDWObject: NSObject

- (NSInteger)addNum:(NSInteger)lhs toNum:(NSInteger)rhs;
@end

@implementation TDWObject

- (NSInteger)addNum:(NSInteger)lhs toNum:(NSInteger)rhs {
    return lhs + rhs;
}

@end

int TDWObjcSum(int a, int b) {
    return [[TDWObject new] addNum:a toNum:b];
}
```

For C++ code it would be just another free function:

```cpp
// mycpp.cpp

#include "ObjcSum.h"


struct S {
    void foo() {
        auto result = TDWObjcSum(10, 15);
    }
};
```

Comment: An error occurred while calling the function 'OBJC' from 'C++'. Edited the question to add the error statement. Is there something I'm missing??

Comment: @Jungwon if you employ the **C-approach** you headers cannot expose any Objective-C-specific details. I.e. it should not contain any `@interface`, `@implementation` or Cocoa Touch framework headers. C++ code knows nothing about Objective-C syntax, it can handle only C functions. In this case the only thing allowed in your `ObjcSum.h` file is the function signature `int TDWObjcSum(int num1, int num2);`. Everything else has to be put into the implementation file if you want to use the header in C or C++ code.

Comment: The error has been resolved. But I am getting another error. `Showing Recent Messages
Undefined symbol: TDWObjcSum(int, int)`

Comment: @Jungwon you need to wrap the function declaration with `extern "C"` guards, so C++ doesn't mangle its name when importing to C++ compilation unit. Included it in my answer