# Using C++ in Objective-C

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, objective-c++

I'm trying to use C++ with Objective-C. My tasks force me to use C++ only for crossplatform core. Goal is to reuse core on different platforms and rewrite only graphics interface. I know Objective-C pretty well, and also some C++. However, when I try to use them together, get a ton of errors.

*For example:*

CppFile.cpp

```cpp
#include "ObjCFile.h"

int main() {
    ObjCFile *objCFile;
}
```

ObjCFile.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ObjCFile : UIViewController

- (void)showInterface;
...
```

With the two files above, I get errors about things that seems completely unrelated, such as `undefined NSString` and so on.

I've tried to look for answers to this problem on Google, and here on StackOverflow and found one approach, but it's not very clear because same C++ class in this case uses 2 type of methods : 1.Implemented outside 2.Implemented inside. And inside methods will call outside methods (C++ class from internal logic must call it’s own methods that implements different logic). There’s no responsibility division (SOLID). You may check this approach link [How to call functions in c++ and objective-c to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75516453/how-to-call-functions-in-c-and-objective-c-to-each-other)

Comment: It's fine to answer your own question, but you still need to ask the question as though you don't already know the answer that you're about to give. That'll make it easier for people to figure out what you're asking. Also, you might find that people give you answers that you weren't expecting. I've rewritten your question from that perspective, but please edit if you feel that I've somehow missed the point of what you're trying to ask.

Comment: @Caleb Indeed! Article would be better but there is 2 moments
First of all when I've searched an answer for my question I haven’t found **any** article about this
And second an article needs a reviewers it's a great chance that my info doesn’t reach those who need it. Notice I'm not professional not even a person who can clearly explain technical Information. I think 90% of people decide this information is lame. My purpose is 10% persons who don’t think that it obvious and there’re no one near who can teach them
And I didn’t mark my answer as accepted
Thanks anyway

Comment: @Caleb sorry for my English it isn’t my native language 
Thanks for fixing my errors

Comment: Твой английский лучше моего русского.  (Your English is better than my Russian.)

Comment: Just rename source file so it has `.mm` extension and you are done.

Comment: @MarekR I need to use pure C++ for multiplatform core

Comment: So what is problem? I see duplicate explains everything. Translation unit which provides bridge must have  `.mm` extension. Objective C interface nicely hides C++. C++ header is also easy to hide Objective C. I did something like this for 5 years (C++ cross platform library with bindings to Objective-C (MacOS/iOS), C# (Windows) and Java - (Android), C++ (Linux)) and bridge to Objective-C was the easiest thing. The Java was hard since JNI is a real pain.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "For my tasks this approach is useless". The answer to the linked question explains why you get the errors and give possible solutions to it

Comment: @MarekR solution from answer above suppose that definitions in C++ class implemented in Objective-C++. It's not very clear because same C++ class in this case uses 2 type of methods : 1.Implemented outside 2.Implemented inside. And inside methods will call outside methods. There’s no responsibility division (SOLID). Using wrapper as a standalone Objective-C++ class gives us that division: C++ calls methods in Objective-C++ Wrapper class and Wrapper calls Objective-C ViewController class. And vice versa

Comment: @TheDreamsWind you’re right about my question. I’ve already fixed it

Comment: @ДенисСолодовник if you want we can discuss what the answer is missing in more details in [the SO chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253370/objective-c-c-interoperability), to avoid extensive discussion in the comment section. (so it can be improved for future readers)

Answer (score -1):

If you have too many errors when combining two languages you need to look at `#include` in your C++ files. You can't `include` UIKit or other specific libraries in C++ files! XCode goes insane and shows a hundreds errors.

To solve this problem you need a **bridge** using Objective-C++. Notice the details!

Bridge.hh (**don't include ObjCFile.h!**)

```
class Bridge {
    public:
    ...
    void showInterface();
}
```

Bridge.mm (**include your Objective-C header here**)

```
#import "ObjCFile.h"

void Bridge::showInterface() {
    ObjCFile *objCFile;
    [objcFile showInterface];
}
```

New CppFile.cpp

```
#include "Bridge.hh"

int main() {
    Bridge *bridge;
    bridge->showInterface();
}
```

That's it!

Many articles I've seen that was *similar* to my article but they *omit* info about XCode libraries.
That confused me.

Comment: Is there a reason that you need a separate bridge file instead of just renaming `CppFile.cpp` to `CppFile.mm` so that it gets compiled as Objective-C++? If you do that, you can access the Obj-C objects directly, although you'll need to do it using Obj-C syntax `(e.g. `[objcFile showInterface]` instead of `objcFile->showInterface()`). Objective-C++'s reason for existing is to allow you to easily use the two languages together -- why not use it?

Comment: Also, it's certainly not the case that "most C++ programmers write their programs on Windows..." C++ is used on a large variety of platforms, from embedded systems to supercomputers.

Comment: @Caleb the point to use C++ is crossplatform core that can be reused.
Of course you can say that use of Kotlin or C# would be better, but my tasks force me to use C++

Comment: @Caleb you’re right about Windows I need to be more correct "most C++ programmers I questioned about my problem"

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using C++, but if you're able to add your own Objective-C header files to your C++ source, then presumably you're also able to choose to compile your C++ using an Objective-C++ compiler. You wouldn't expect a C++ compiler to work if you #included a bunch of Python code, right? It's the same with Objective-C -- if you include it in your C++ code, the compiler won't know what to do with it. Using the bridge file is one way to handle the problem, but it's extra work compared to just using a compiler that knows about Objective-C.

Comment: If you're sticking with strict C++ (no Objective-C++), then you do need to keep Objective-C code out of it, so the bridge solution is the right one. If that's the case, you should probably edit the question to make it clear that you have this restriction. As you asked it, and I restated it, the question suggests that your goal is to mix Obj-C and C++, not keep them separate.